Question 5, section 19 of Munkres Analysis on Manifolds
Let $A$ be an open rectifiable set in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Given the point $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $ p_n > 0 $, let $ S $ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by the equation
$$ S = \{ x \mid x = (1-t)a + tp, \text{ where } a \in A \times \{0\} \text{ and } 0 < t < 1 \}. $$
Then $ S $ is the union of all open line segments in $\mathbb{R}^n$ joining $p$ to points of $ A \times \{0\}$; its closure is called the cone with base $ A \times \{0\} $ and vertex $ p $.
(a) Define a diffeomorphism $ g $ of $ A \times (0,1) $ with $ S $.
(b) Find $ v(S) $ in terms of $ v(A) $.
The diffeomorphism I thought of was $g(a,t)=(1-t)a+tp$ but I can't prove that this is in fact a diffeomorphism and I also have no idea how to do a (b).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

For (b), the idea is that the diffeomorphism $g$ provides a change of coordinates to make the problem of finding the volume $v(S)$ easier. There is a nice "change of coordinates" formula found earlier in the section.

Also for (a), there is a slight problem in your definition of $g$. In particular, $a$ lives in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ but $p$ lives in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so technically it doesn't make sense to consider $(1-t)a+tp$.
